# Windows task manager javaw.exe memory vs Java Mission Control

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I'm helping develop a java application using my Windows 7 machine, which has Java 8 Update 45. I'm noticing a substantial difference in how much memory Windows Task Manager says is being used by the application (through the javaw.exe Image), and what Eclipse Memory Analyzer/Java Mission Control reports.

Example:  Java Mission Control reports 150 MB of Java Heap Memory used, while Windows says 303 MB of Working Set used for javaw.exe.  I understand there is probably some overhead for JVM itself, GC, etc.

But I also see it doing GC. After a bit of clicking around to make memory grow, JMC shows GC was performed and says 200 MB of heap used.  Windows reports 619 MB (it never went down).  Is Windows not displaying memory usage by Java properly?  Something with the application cause this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the JVM starts up, it allocates a continuous region of memory for the heap.  This memory can be turned into real memory lazily but almost never is passed back to the operating system.

The heap is but one region of memory the JVM uses.  It may be the most important to you but when your heap is really small, it can be small compared to the other regions the JVM uses.  This includes

- native memory e.g. direct ByteBuffers.
- GUI native components.
- shared libraries.
- the jar files.
- the metaspace (or perm gen)
- the thread stack memories.

> Is Windows not displaying memory usage by Java properly?

Windows shows all the memory used, not just the portion used by the heap.

> Something with the application cause this to happen?

Windows has no idea how much of the maximum heap size you are using.

Comment: How do I keep the application from taking up all of Windows memory?  Is there a way to pass it back to the OS?

Comment: @user1795832 You need to give the application the amount of memory you want it to use and let it manage the memory itself.  Setting the maximum heap is not setting the maximum memory but a couple of hundred MB for the other things the JVM does is usually not a concern (unless you have a small device)

Comment: What do you mean by giving the application the amount of memory I want it to use? Just the amount of heap it can use via Xmx and let it go from there?

Comment: @user1795832 You have to take into account that the -Xmx controls just one portion of the memory, and if you are trying to tune down the memory usage, a small portion of the total memory. If you have a larger heap like 64 GB, then the heap may be the only thing you have to worry about.

Comment: I've tried doing all of that, the Windows process just shows it keeps taking more memory when jconsole says there is plenty of heap available for the jvm to use.  I put a max of 512 MB, once it hits ~450 or so it garbage collects, and the heap goes back down as expected.  But the Windows java process does not go down.  And whenever I click in the application to make it use memory from the heap, it uses the heap, but Windows process continues to go up.

Comment: @user1795832 are you saying it goes up without limit or is the limit something like 800 MB if the heap is 500 MB.

Comment: Windows goes up without limit.  As far as I can tell through jconsole/MAT, heap behaves as it should with garbage collection when it hits heap limit. But Windows javaw.exe process just goes up and never goes down.  Almost like it doesn't use the heap available, rather keeps pulling from Windows.

Comment: @user1795832 it is possible to have a memory leak in native memory. This could be due to a bug in the application.

Comment: I've looked at everything and can't explain it.  Any suggestions how to identify a leak in native memory?

Comment: @user1795832 on linux you can look at the memory mappings and even the raw memory in another process but I don't know if you can do that on windows.